# Should triggers be implemented in application layer or database layer?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, triggers

i am doing an assignment about creating a database in mySQL that needs to have some sort of a change log. I am also using JDBC to create an application that connects to the database. The change log need to be updated whenever the recipe-table gets a new row, updates a row or deletes a row. The change-table has newRecipeID, oldRecipe, date and userID which is the id of the user who did the change.

I did some research and concluded that triggers would be the best choice to do this. However, i do not know how to get the ID of the current user, through the database. However, it can easily be done in the application. This made me think that i can move the trigger to the application layer.

Is this a bad idea? should triggers always be done in the database layer, or is it okay to move them to the application?

Comment: Keep them in the db. Safer, faster etc.

Comment: But the database doesn't know who is doing the operation. so how can i get the userID through the database?

Comment: I'd say it's ok to do that in the application, especially if there's more work involved such as getting the user's id. The application generally is more flexible but the downside is that it's normally slower and the application's "trigger" might not always be executed, e.g. when someone edits the table via a SQL client.

Comment: my guess is maybe triggers are NOT the best choice... auditing records is a common feature, that is implemented in many libraries like "envers hibernate": https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/ (if you are using hibernate)

Comment: i am not allowed to use external libraries

Comment: btw jdbc already is an external library... (at least the driver)

Comment: true, but jdbc is the only library we may use